# Custom Sticker iMessage Application, how to link to iOS store?

Tags: ios, pack, imessage

I am developing a custom sticker message application, this will exist independent of a containing/existing iOS Application. My question is, is it possible to add a link to existing iOS App in iOS app store to my stickers in my custom sticker app. 
i.e.:

1. User downloads sticker app from message app store, sends a custom sticker to friend
2. Friend receives and presses sticker and is directed to iOS app store

Is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

The behaviour of such case will be :

if the user that receive the message from your iMessage app has not yet installed the app, he will be redirect to the **iMessage Store**, not the App Store.

Have a look here : https://developer.apple.com/reference/messages/msmessage

> iOS device without the iMessage app installed. The system opens the
>   App Store for iMessage and prompts the user to install the iMessage
>   app.